# Help me in understanding the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I want to understand this circuit.

The Circuit:

[image: Laser_Driver_Ckt]

My experimental layout:

[image: My Circuit illustration]

Question :

According to the circuit.. It mentions that the "*The Thermal Pad is to be connected to a Ground Plane (GND, AGND1. . . 6) on the PCB*."

What does this mean. And why have they named it as AGND and GND ( high-lighted boxes in fig.1) ?? Does it mean I have to ground them physically separate or is it already done like they mentioned about the thermal pad grounding ??

Comment: Please add the question as text and crop/scale the third image to appropriate sizes.

Comment: @jippie Yes, yes, a thousand times yes. Posting a question in this manner is completely unacceptable. Text in an image not only prevents searching, it also means that if the secondary site ever goes down or the picture is changed/deleted/defaced, the question changes/disappears/becomes something else totally different. Vote to close until OP fixes this question.

Comment: I'd bet that there is an application note covering grounding best practices for either the IC that you're testing or the evaluation board that you're using.  Have you looked at the manufacturer's resources?

Answer (score 2):

The negatives for both VDD and Vlda both go to GND. Shouldn't matter where; ground is ground. Someone please correct me if I'm mistaken.